# pyclamd - 'ERROR', 'File path check failure: Permission denied

Tags: python

I'm wrote a simple code for scanning the file using Calmav and Python.

Project Structure :-

- main.py
- test.txt

Code :-

```
import pyclamd

clamd = pyclamd.ClamdUnixSocket()
result = clamd.scan_file("/home/calmav/scan_file/code/test.txt")
print(result)
```

When I try to run the code it shown me a error msg

```
{'/home/calmav/scan_file/code/test.txt': ('ERROR', 'File path check failure: Permission denied.')}
```

Comment: Does the file exist?  Do you have permission to read to the file?

Comment: yes the file exits but the calmav is runnnig from docker